# Не прогружается фоновое изображение после публикации на IIS проекта C# asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis

Проект C# asp.net core mvc, в нем есть главная страница "Home.cshtml", которой задаю фоновое изображение:

```
@model CollectVoters.DTO.LoginModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                background: url(/img/Orenburg_black_with.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
                background-size: cover;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
```

Есть _Layout.cshtml которая подгружает её:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - CollectVoters</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/font-glyphicons.css">
    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    </environment>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <h1><a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index"></a></h1>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="Index">Администратор</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Friends" asp-action="Index">Личный кабинет</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">Регистрация</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
        @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

При тестировании из среды разработки на IIS Express страница Home прогружается с фоновым изображением нормально, но при публикации на IIS сервера фоновое изображение не прогружается.

В чем причина и как это можно исправить?

Структура проекта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запуске на сервере iis за картинкой обращается по пути http://localhost/img/Oren...jpg

Пробовал подыматься на 2 уровня выше, а потом указывал путь у нужной папке:

```
background: url(../../wwwroot/img/Orenburg_black_with.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

В итоге сервер обращается по следующему пути:

> http://localhost/wwwroot/img/Orenburg...jpg

что соответствует пути по которому на сервере находится изображение, но выдает ошибку

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
> (Not Found)

Пробовал в файл css/site.css прописывать:

```
    body {
    /* Margin bottom by footer height */
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    background: url(~/img/Orenburg_black_with.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Не сработало

Как прописать относительный путь так чтобы он при публикации шел в нужную папку проекта и при отладке тоже?

Comment: В css кажется надо через тильду указывать, вот так: `background: url(~/img/Orenburg_black_with.jpg)`

Comment: @AK, не срабатывает

Comment: Пробовал подыматься на 2 уровня выше, а потом указывал путь у нужной папке:

    background: url(../../wwwroot/img/Orenburg_black_with.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;

В итоге сервер обращается по следующему пути: 

> http://localhost/wwwroot/img/Orenburg...jpg

что соответствует пути по которому на сервере находится изображение, но выдает ошибку 

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
> (Not Found)

Comment: А если вписать css-код в файл `css/site.css` (с тильдой) то ошибка пропадает? )

Comment: @AK, это как? Покажите

Comment: @AK, я пробовал там прописывать вот так, не помогло: body {
    /* Margin bottom by footer height */
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    background: url(~/img/Orenburg_black_with.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

Comment: Давайте по шагам. Шаг 1. Открывается ли из браузера файл по прямой ссылке? по serverurl/img/Orenburg...jpg или файла нет? Шаг 2. Если посмотреть исходный код страницы в браузере, то как там url выглядит ?

Comment: @AK, 1. в браузере он открывается по следующей прямой ссылке - "file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/collectorvoters/wwwroot/img/Orenburg_black_with.jpg".

Comment: @AK, 2. если прописать путь "/img/Orenburg_black_with.jpg", то он обращается -  http://localhost/img/Oren...jpg

Comment: @AK, 2. если прописать путь "../../wwwroot/img/Orenburg_black_with.jpg" - "http://localhost/wwwroot/img/Orenburg...jpg"

Comment: Извините, но `file://` -- это не протокол интернета, это можно сделать вообще без IIS - просто открыть. Вы утверждаете, что у вас из IIS файл виден, значит тогда нужно ставить под сомнение ваше утверждение, что в IIS нормально смотрится. Не настроен у вас IIS. Когда будет доступен по адресу http://yourserver/img/Orendurg.jpg - тогда возвращайтесь поговорим, пока же у вас код работает, в программировании ошибок нет (IIS Express работает), а вот сисадминская часть - настройка IIS не сделана.

Comment: Это вопрос не о программировании и можете не приводить примеры, как вы меняете в коде путь к файлу. Показывайте настройки IIS и доказывайте, что у вас IIS корректно настроен.

Comment: @AK, где можно посмотреть пример как он настраивается?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122949/discussion-between-a-k-and-vlad-i-mir).

Comment: @AK, написал в чат

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема с путями. Посмотрите в инструментах разработчика браузера откуда он пытается загрузить изображение(F12 или Ctrl-Shift-I), возможно путь к изображению потребуется привести к виду:

```
"../img/Orenburg_black_with.jpg"
```

Или просто убрать слеш

```
"img/Orenburg_black_with.jpg"
```

Но это только предположение, так как я не знаю, как располагаются файлы в Вашем проекте.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос структурой проекта. При запуске на сервере iis за картинкой обращается по пути http://localhost/img/Oren...jpg

Как прописать относительный путь так чтобы он при публикации шел в нужную папку проекта и при отладке тоже?